# Applying a separate theme to Dialog from Activity

Tags: android, dialog, themes

I have an Activity which has a custom theme applied to it in the AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".FoodSearchActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
  </activity>
```

Clicking a `ListView` item on this Activity allows a custom `Dialog` window (I created a custom class `FoodDialog` that extends `Dialog`) to pop up. This `Dialog` window is inheriting this theme, which is making it look pretty ugly.

Is there anyway I can apply a separate theme to the `Dialog` window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a custom style on top of the `Activity`'s theme in your `Dialog` subclass by calling [Dialog.Dialog(Context context, int themeResId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog(android.content.Context,%20int)) in the constructor, i.e.:

```
public FoodDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.foodDialogStyle);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Quick, elegant and simple! The way I like it. Worked perfectly. Thanks!